# Не пойму почему setState не обновляет состояние

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет!)))
Читала и искала решение этой ошибки, но хоть убейте - не могу найти ответ (или не пойму).
Про асинхронность setState знаю. Вроде делаю все ок) Но не обновляется переменная isBurgerMenuOpened. То есть при нажатии на кнопку меню, функция burgerMenuOpen срабатывает, isBurgerMenuOpened меняется на true, а классу burger__navigation добавляется соответствующий класс. Но вот когда я нажимаю на burger__close-button, то burgerMenuClose не срабатывает. Стейт-переменная не меняется. И сообственно, класс не убирается.

Что я не так делаю?((((

```
function BurgerMenu() {
  const [isBurgerMenuOpened, setIsBurgerMenuOpened]  = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() =>{
    console.log(isBurgerMenuOpened);

  }, [isBurgerMenuOpened] );


  function burgerMenuOpen() {
    setIsBurgerMenuOpened(true);
  }

  function burgerMenuClose() {
    setIsBurgerMenuOpened(false);
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={burgerMenuOpen} className="burger">
      <div className={`burger__navigation ${isBurgerMenuOpened && 'burger__navigation_opened'}`}>
        <div onClick={burgerMenuClose} className="burger__close-button"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Что за rw в burgerMenuClose?

Comment: уже убрала)) то случайно было записано

Comment: Проверять лень, но событие onClick «всплывает» так что ваш клик по крестику вызывает сначала burgerMenuClose, а потом «доплывает» до внешнего div и вызывает burgerMenuOpen

Comment: все, блин, поняла))))

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо [Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten), из-за вложенности в блоки, срабатывало сразу 2 события. Разобралась, вынесла блок burger__close-button отдельно и все заработало)))